# Google Drive 15 GO but API return me 16.1 GO

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I used the google drive API to find out how much space I have left on my drive.

```
result = GoogleDrive.service.about().get(fields = "quotaBytesTotal, quotaBytesUsed").execute()
```

And it return me : `{"quotaBytesTotal": "16106127360", "quotaBytesUsed": "687529945"}`

16106127360 Bytes = 16.10612736 Go

687529945 Bytes = 0.687529945 Go

But, If I verify on my drive :

[image]

Why `16.1 =! 15`  and `687 != 848`
Why I haven't the same result from using API and from drive UI

Comment: Use gibibits (powers of 1024), not gigabits (powers of 1000).  15 * 1024^3 == 16,106,127,360.  I can’t explain the free space however.

Comment: Thanks a lot !  I will try to understand for the space used ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each new prefix for `bytes`, you must multiply by 1024 instead of 1000:

```
                         1 kB =          1024 Bytes
          1 MB =      1024 kB =     1,048,576 Bytes
1 GB = 1024 MB = 1,048,576 kB = 1,073,741,824 Bytes


15 Gigabytes = (15 * 1,073,741,824 Bytes) = 16,106,127,360 Bytes
```

Which is your total Bytes Quota.

As for `quotaBytesUsed` - this accounts for files stored in Drive *only*, whereas the quota viewable in the UI includes files that are stored in other services that also use the same storage. As per the documentation on the [About resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/about#resource):

> | Property Name | Value | Description | Notes |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | `quotaBytesUsed` | `long` | The number of quota bytes used by Google Drive. |  |

To get the value reflected in the Drive UI, instead, use the field value `quotaBytesUsedAggregate`:

> | Property Name | Value | Description | Notes |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | `quotaBytesUsedAggregate` | `long` | The number of quota bytes used by all Google apps (Drive, Picasa, etc.). |  |

```
result = GoogleDrive.service.about().get(fields = "quotaBytesTotal, quotaBytesUsedAggregate").execute()
```

This should return the accurate value.

Comment: Je n'avais toujours pas la bonne valeur avec l'API v2, je suis passé sur l'API v3 : "storageQuota": {
    "limit": long,
    "usage": long,
    "usageInDrive": long,
    "usageInDriveTrash": long
  },
Mais aucun de ces paramètres ne renvoie mon 848,9 .
result is : {'storageQuota': {'limit': '16106127360', 'usage': '890087624', 'usageInDrive': '687529945', 'usageInDriveTrash': '8770337'}}
I don't understand why it is not exactly what it display

Comment: but here : https://one.google.com/storage It display 0.82 GO. different to 0.848 .. I don't understand why google drive doesn't show me the same values depending on where I am

Comment: @MathieuOlivesDelmas 890,097,624 / 1024 / 1024 = 848.85 MB